# CSS :: Fixed header without setting position:fixed

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a php page which includes header page(navigation bar). I want to display navigation bar as fixed header but whenever change its position to fixed, it removes scrollbars (horizantal and vertical) and I am not able to scroll the page. If I want to keep my header fixed and I don't want to make position fixed. How can I achieve this ?

headerpage.php :

```
     <div id="header" style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100px;">
          <ul>
               <li>..... </li>
               <li>..... </li>
               <li>..... </li>
          </ul>
     </div>
```

anotherpage.php :

```
      <?php
              require("headerpage.php");
      ?>

      <body>
            some code....
      </body>
```

Since there are 2 pages, I have created jsFiddle for my headerpage.php.

http://jsfiddle.net/vVptE/

Comment: Are you including the HTML on the top (which you've named headerpage.php) in anotherpage.php, but call it header.php there instead? If so, besides from the different filename, the div-stuff is part of the HTML body. The head-part is for including css, javascript, meta-tags etc... Although the head-tags are missing as well... oO

Comment: It was just typo. I have updated code.

Comment: `position:fixed` is what you want. What scroll bars are being removed? If you can post a jsfiddle or plunker we can help resolve you layout issue.

Comment: Why not use "position:fixed" for this?

Comment: Hi Matthew - I have created jsfiddle, its not for 2 page but my css is given there. http://jsfiddle.net/vVptE/

Comment: Be careful with this, it kicks ass while scrolling in Apple devices as Apple adds scroll effects and also browser will be doing lots of work to accomplish your scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Hey jesper did u use position:relative with position:abosulte and fixed as if you want to fix your header then you have to use all of three and may be you have to use z-index too or else there will be probelm with your site content if they have so..can you please give us proper jsfiddle so we can help..as i cant see anything instead of header..so for doing position fixed you need other part too..
P.S. i want to help so tell me and i will try..:)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually I cannot create jsfiddle as it involves 2 php pages and i dont know how to create jsfiddle with them. Still I can try to explain, there are 2 pages (e.g Page 1 and Page 2). Now  page 1 has navigation bar and Page 2 includes Page 1. In order to fix header, I will have to keep navigation bar's position as fixed. If I set position fixed, it removes both scrollbars of my webpage. Now my question is - how can I set fixed header without loosing both scrollbars ? I hope this might helpful.

Comment: Sorry but still m not getting you..can you please edit your qustion and will put your code so we can see the problem as by your js we cant get anything so please edit the code so we can help..or else mail me your 2 page php code on testuser597@yahoo.com..so i can try to help..thanx :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Leo, I was preparing code for you and at the same moment I realized my mistake. I have not provided z-index to appropriate div's. :) Now the problem is resolved and its working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Really thanx for vote up as i really need that..:) and m happy that i was able to help..:)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.pin](http://webpop.github.io/jquery.pin/) will achieve sticking elements, just like `position:fixed;`.
Just download it, then implement it like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/jquery.pin-plugin'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(function(){
       $("#header").pin();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: FYI. this uses `position:fixed`

Comment: Okay. Will choose other words

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to use position fixed. Also no plug in.

Answer (score 0):

Place top:0; at your header css remove position:fixed;